# Is it possible to decrement result number by 7, 3, 2 in one loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm new to javascript and my weakness has always been for-loops. However, right now I'm 95% sure, that I need to use for-loops to achieve my goal.

For an instance: I'm trying to decrement number 45 at first by 7, till it reaches 38:

```py
for (var j = 45; j >= 38; j -=7){
console.log (j);
}
```

Then I would like to decrement 38 by 3, till it reaches 32:

```py
for (var l = 38; l >= 32; l -=3){
console.log (l);
}
```

And then again decrement result by 2 till it reaches 0:

```py
for (var s = 32; s >= 0; s -=2){
console.log (s);
}
```

And here's the issue that I'm facing: how can I assign these 3 for-loops to one variable, so that when I'm calling for variable, it displays:

```
45
38
35
32
30
28
.
.
0
```

Or is there a better alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'when I'm calling for variable'? Can you show us the sort of line of code that you want to produce this output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to decrement result number by 7, 3, 2 in one loop in javascript?

Yes, it is possible.

You could take an object with the values for changing the step variable for the wanted interval.

```js
var steps = { 45: 7, 38: 3, 32: 2 },
    step,
    j;

for (j = 45; j >= 0; j -= (step = steps[j] || step)) {
    console.log(j);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I understand `step = steps[j] || step, j -= step` as "if no object are found with current `j` value, `step` value remains and `j` is decremented by `step` value"? I'm a bit disturbed with the `||` and `,` part in the final expression.

Comment: right. if not found take the old value. it's the same as an imperative `if`. the comma inside of the *final-expression* (update part) of the [`for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) separates the expressions.look at the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Comment: This is an elegant solution, in JS that is. Basically, if there is a value assigned to `steps[ j ]`, then `step` is set and `||` evaluates the prior expression first. Otherwise `step` is just `step`. Finally there is the decrementation. I find it at the same time elegant as well as hard to read. The reason I say this is a JS thing, is because in most languages you may get into trouble with `steps[j]` if there is no element in `steps` assigned to that index.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I didn't know this syntax. This is smart, according to the fact the first element will always be found.

Answer (score -1):

You can just modify your iteration interval depending on what range your current iterator is in.

```
var x = 7;
for( var i = 45; i > 0; i -= x )
{
    if( i <= 38 && i > 32 ) x = 3;
    else if( i <= 32 ) x = 2;
    console.log( i );
}
```

Comment: You should change the , to ; in `for( var i = 45,` Furthermore, have you tried the code before posting it? Result is: `45, 43, 41 ... 1`

Comment: My bad. I meant the second answer. This one didn't work for me also. I marked correct answer now

Comment: I reviewed the code and fixed the issues. Works correctly on my end now. Thank you for pointing out, @KooiInc